# What is the difference between chain and chainman in the NodeContext in the Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, c++

In the [`NodeContext`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/306ccd4927a2efe325c8d84be1bdb79edeb29b04/src/node/context.h#L43) structure there are two members named [`chainman`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/306ccd4927a2efe325c8d84be1bdb79edeb29b04/src/node/context.h#L54) and [`chain`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/306ccd4927a2efe325c8d84be1bdb79edeb29b04/src/node/context.h#L57). `chainman`
is instance of `ChainstateManager` and `chain` is instance of `interfaces::Chain`. What is the differences between these two? What is the differences and why do we need both?

```
//! NodeContext struct containing references to chain state and connection
//! state.
//!
//! This is used by init, rpc, and test code to pass object references around
//! without needing to declare the same variables and parameters repeatedly, or
//! to use globals. More variables could be added to this struct (particularly
//! references to validation objects) to eliminate use of globals
//! and make code more modular and testable. The struct isn't intended to have
//! any member functions. It should just be a collection of references that can
//! be used without pulling in unwanted dependencies or functionality.
struct NodeContext {
    //! libbitcoin_kernel context
    std::unique_ptr<kernel::Context> kernel;
    //! Init interface for initializing current process and connecting to other processes.
    interfaces::Init* init{nullptr};
    std::unique_ptr<AddrMan> addrman;
    std::unique_ptr<CConnman> connman;
    std::unique_ptr<CTxMemPool> mempool;
    std::unique_ptr<const NetGroupManager> netgroupman;
    std::unique_ptr<CBlockPolicyEstimator> fee_estimator;
    std::unique_ptr<PeerManager> peerman;
    std::unique_ptr<ChainstateManager> chainman;
    std::unique_ptr<BanMan> banman;
    ArgsManager* args{nullptr}; // Currently a raw pointer because the memory is not managed by this struct
    std::unique_ptr<interfaces::Chain> chain;
    //! List of all chain clients (wallet processes or other client) connected to node.
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<interfaces::ChainClient>> chain_clients;
    //! Reference to chain client that should used to load or create wallets
    //! opened by the gui.
    interfaces::WalletLoader* wallet_loader{nullptr};
    std::unique_ptr<CScheduler> scheduler;
    std::function<void()> rpc_interruption_point = [] {};

    //! Declare default constructor and destructor that are not inline, so code
    //! instantiating the NodeContext struct doesn't need to #include class
    //! definitions for all the unique_ptr members.
    NodeContext();
    ~NodeContext();
};
```

My assumptions are:

- `ChainstateManager` manages `Chainstate`s which are `m_ibd_chainstate` and `m_snapshot_chainstate`.
- `Chainstate` has all data of a chain.

While `interfaces::Chain` is used for external components such as wallet, the only possible reason that comes to my mind is that the `chain` member is for external users of `bitcoind`. And by this fact, the implementation of `interface::chain` must be only a simple wrapper over the `ChainstateManager`, because I think all logic is implemented there.